# php exec ping command issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec

I have a website created in codeigniter. I'm using php exec("ping") command to ping some servers, switches/Routers and copiers to make sure they are up. when a device goes down, I get an email telling me which device is down and what time it went down.

the problem I'm running to is, I have a foreach statement that gets the ip address of every device from the database, and run the exec command on it. If let's say the device that is in the 5th position is down, all the other devices after it shows that they are down, even if they are up. I'm not sure why. I was using the fsockopen function before the exec, I was happy with it, I just had a problem that it pings the device multiple times and every time it fails it sends an email, so we get a lot of email telling that one device is down.

My code is below, if you guys have any suggestion, please let me know. Thanks

```
 foreach ($devices->result() as $device)
{
            

    $ping_host = exec("ping -n 1 ".$device->ip, $output, $result);
                

            if($result==0)
            {
                if(count(preg_grep('/Destination host unreachable/i', $output)) == 0)
                {
//This will show blinking green next device that is up                  

    $ping = "<img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_green_light.gif\"/><img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_green_light.gif\"/>";

                                    }
                else
                {
                    $ping = "<img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_red_light.gif\"/><img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_red_light.gif\"/>";
                    $this->email->from('sender email address', 'name');
                    $this->email->to(recipient email);
                                        
                    $this->email->subject($device->host.' is down');
                    $this->email->message('the following devices are not reached.<br/>
                                            Host Name: '.$device->host.'<br/>
                                            IP Address: '.$device->ip.'
                                        ');
                    
                    $this->email->send();
                                    
                }
                    
                
                
            }
            elseif ($result==1)
            {
                $ping = "<img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_red_light.gif\"/><img src=\"".base_url()."assets/images/icons/blinking_red_light.gif\"/>";
                    
                
                
            }
    
            echo '  
            <tr id="'.$device->id.'" class="selected_tr">
            <td  align="center"><img src="'.$device->img_path.'" /><br/>
            <a href="'.$device->host.'">'.ucfirst($device->host).'</a></td>
            <td align="center">
            <a href="'.$device->ip.'">'.$device->ip.'</a></td>
            <td align="center">'.$device->port.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$device->category.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$ping.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="5" height="10px"><hr></td></tr>
            ';
            
}
```

Comment: Have you output the results for each command, what do they show?

Comment: Yep I did a print_r on the $output, and it shows that all the devices are up except the one that is down. But when I look in the webpage, it shows all the devices down after the one that is down and sends an email for each devices teeling us it's down even if they are up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

The output from the exec is being appended to the `$output` array, so the previous outputs are still present in the array.

Comment: You got it Pudge601. that fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: by the way in case somebody having the same issue, this is what i did. I added unset($output) before the exec function.

Comment: No problem =] don't forget to mark the thread as resolved if the problem is fixed :P

Comment: How do you do that? sorry

Comment: Ermm.. never actually asked a question before, so not 100% sure.. as far as I know, there should be tick next to my answer that you can click to say you've accepted the answer, this post seems to explain it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235